# Android Lollipop: ImageView ignoring fitsSystemWindows attribute (transparent status bar)

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm currently working on an app for which I want to enable a transparent status bar. I want an `ImageView` (which I require for its `scaleType` attribute) to cover the entirety of the screen so that the image will show below the status bar. Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/picture" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            (...toolbar stuff...)
        />

        (...some other stuff...)

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see, it's a regular `DrawerLayout`. Notice that the `DrawerLayout`, the `RelativeLayout` and the `ImageView` all have the `fitsSystemWindows` attribute set to true.

My problem is: **If I set a background resource (like a color or a picture) to either the `DrawerLayout` or the `RelativeLayout` in the above code, I can see that color or picture "below" the status bar, exactly as I want it, but the `ImageView`'s 'src' drawable is always shown under it, as if it ignored the `fitsSystemWindows` attribute completely.**

I have the following attributes in my theme:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
```

With primary_dark being a semitransparent black (this shouldn't matter anyway, since as I said, this seems to be an issue exclusive to my `ImageView`. The transparent status bar works perfect for either the `DrawerLayout` or the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for me

You have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`in every viewGroup params.
Try to left only one in ImageView.

Or completely remove all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
fitSystemWindows
```

does not work in RelativeLayout. Use a FrameLayout or a ViewGroup extending FrameLayout

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` extends `View` and does not override it's method `onApplyWindowInsets`.
Default logic defined in `View` is described in docs:

> By default if a view's {@link #setFitsSystemWindows(boolean) fitsSystemWindows}
>        * property is set then the view will consume the system window insets and apply them
>        * as padding for the view.

And the same logic applies to `RelativeLayout`, so i'd recommend you to add the following line to your `Activity`/`Fragment` code to skip applying insets:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(relativeLayout) { _, insets -> insets }
```

As a result, the top padding will be gone.
Transparent status bar color is also required to be set in order to see your view beneath it:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fitSystemWindows` doesn't expand a view to "fit the system window", it rather gives view a chance to handle it in desired way. And by default ImageView doesn't take this offer, in contrast to DrawerLayout or CoordinatorLayout. You need to teach ImageView to use system window area. Try to add something like that in your `onCreate()` method:

```
imageView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((view, windowInsets) -> {
    view.setPaddingRelative(
            view.getPaddingStart(),
            windowInsets.getStableInsetTop(),
            view.getPaddingEnd(),
            view.getPaddingBottom()
    );
    return windowInsets;
});
```

You may need to return changed windowInsets object in order to let other views with 'fitsSystemWindows' works properly altogether.

Comment: Here I found very good link how to deal with windowInsets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38929893/755313

Answer (score -1):

Because `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` will add a padding to the `ImageView`, so the src is below the status bar. The padding size is the insets (the status bar height ).
You can use the [FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout) to solve this problem.