# Components in the new activity drawn under status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I used `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`
to make my navigation drawer move behind the status bar. But now when I create a new activity, it makes the whole activity to move behind status bar too (like the textview behind the status bar in the image:

[image]

Also I want the status bar color to match the app theme in the new activity.

New activity's java file:

```
public class AddStudent extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_student);
}
```

New activity's xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.gupta.aayush.tuitionmanager.AddStudent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should check the xml layout file for the new activity and look for placement of the navigation drawer and where it is being placed at. The new activity's java file should also be applying the navigation drawer somewhere in the view. As for the status bar, I do not believe you can change the color. You should make the app fullscreen, that way the status bar is hidden and you don't have to worry about its color

Comment: @EricReyna I have not done anything on the Java or xml file yet. There's only one line code i.e setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_student); (add student is the new activity). As for the xml file, I have only added the text view (I am adding that to the post too). Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) to your root `LinearLayout`.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38929893/1083957) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: It did help a bit. The problem is that the color of status bar changed to grey and I don't want that either. I have primary color in the theme and would like status bar's color to be primarydark

Comment: Then why are you setting `windowTranslucentStatus` if you want the status bar to be primary dark?

Comment: For the navigation drawer in main activity. But I don't want that behavior for other activities in the app.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/1083957) how to set status bar color.

Comment: I cleared the FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS and it kind of worked. Thanks

Comment: As a newcomer in the forum: if you receive an answer to your question - mark it as accepted.