# Controls behind statusbar with ViewPager & fitsSystemWindow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a `ViewPager` with `Fragments` which contain fullscreen images and some bottom aligned controls.

I want to make sure the controls do not disappear behind the translucent navigation bar with `fitsSystemWindow` but I can't seem to make it work...

It does work when I use the same xml without the `ViewPager` so it seems the `ViewPager` "breaks" the ability to use `fitsSystemWindow`.

Code I have for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is what I have for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/initial_background_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_icon_offset"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_icon_offset"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_icon_offset"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/info_button"
            style="@style/button_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/button_info"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            style="@style/button_icon"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/info_button"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/button_icon_divider"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/like_button"
            android:background="@drawable/button_share"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/like_button"
            style="@style/button_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_like"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So this is what I end up with... But I want the buttons to appear **above** the navigation bar.

[image: This is what I dont want]

Answer (score 0):

First, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38929893/1083957) answer concerning `WindowInset`s. Then you'll understand, that your root layout - `FrameLayout`, won't ever dispatch `WindowInset`s to `ViewPager`.

Use [`ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View,%20android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener)) API to dispatch `WindowInset`s to `ViewPager` and make your `ViewPager` fit window insets, i.e. apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to both `ViewPager` and it's parent.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I read up on it. What I don't get is that it works if I use a similar layout in an activity, even if I wrap my buttons inside a FrameLayout multiple times. Then `fitsSystemWindows` still works inside the nested child view.

Answer (score 0):

> Just change/remove this in your style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...    
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

> if still not working? and you're using `NestedScrollView` then add "android:clipToPadding"

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_green"
            android:clipToPadding="false" <--add this
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add margin bottom to the buttons to place them above the nav bar.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: He is looking for the navigation bar size, not the action bar. You should also avoid relying on system attributes, use WindowInsets instead.