# The right view for fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, xml, statusbar, transparent, navigationbar

I wanna make the Navigation Bar totally transparent and the status bar either transparent or translucent !

so I added these line inside  `v21/styles`

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

and this inside the `onCreate`

```
   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

and this in the root layout

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

The navigation bar shows transparent successfully, but the status bar overlapped..! I tried to move the last line in every Layout in the xml but no luck.. sometimes it stopped overlapping but the nav bar no longer stays transparent..! Any help?

[image]
[image]

**The full XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#2d2b30">


<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
  app:titleTextColor="@color/white"/>


<FrameLayout

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/decoratoin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:alpha="0.017"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/decoration0"/>


  <!-- The Linearlayout with id="rootView"  is the one that contains the major views  -->

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

      android:id="@+id/card"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:padding="5dp"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="#da2e2c30"
      app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
      app:cardElevation="5dp">

      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
          android:id="@+id/txt"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="95dp"
          android:layout_margin="2dp"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:maxLines="4"
          android:text="ooooooooooo"
          android:textColor="#ffff"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          autofit:minTextSize="12sp"/>

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/swipe_arrow"
          android:layout_width="40dp"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
          android:alpha="0.1"
          android:src="@drawable/swipe_icon"/>

      </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/reset"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/nums_max"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btn_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/azkar_list"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">


      <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#2d2b30"
        custom:arc_bottom_text=" "
        custom:arc_bottom_text_size="35dp"
        custom:arc_finished_color="@color/colorAccent"
        custom:arc_progress="55"
        custom:arc_stroke_width="20dp"
        custom:arc_suffix_text=" "
        custom:arc_text_color="#84e43b"
        custom:arc_text_size="45dp"
        custom:arc_unfinished_color="#2cf2f2f1"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/check"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

 </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43848091/1083957) answer.

Comment: @azizbekian well, after I removed `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from my xml and then added `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` method instead for my toolbar as you explained in the answer, It worked :D !! I read in the answer why this way works, but couldn't exactly understand what you meant by **(...with this the root layout would consume WindowInsets..)** can explain more if you can..!

Comment: Make you have read [this post at medium](https://medium.com/@azizbekian/windowinsets-24e241d4afb9) where I've tried to do my best describing how it works.

Comment: great..will do now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using android:layout_below and layout_above?

Comment: these are used in `RelativeLayout` and mine is `LinearLayout` and I don't think this would solve the issue.!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@azizbekian**,  I removed `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from my xml and then added this listener to my toolbar..! It worked :D

```
  toolbar.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
  @Override
  public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsets insets) {
    ((MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams()).topMargin =
        insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
    return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
  }
});
```

More details about this can be found on his [medium article.](https://medium.com/@azizbekian/windowinsets-24e241d4afb9)