# Determine content area without navigation bar and status bar

Tags: android, android-view, android-statusbar, android-window, windowinsets

An Android app uses full screen showing content behind the navigation bar, status bar, and toolbar. I'd like to have some contents **not** behind these bars.  How to determine the area without these bars?  As my understanding, the locations of some bars are device dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where [`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) would come handy. Applying this to your view would make it have necessary padding so that it won't be laid out below system views.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585225/what-are-windowinsets/38929893#38929893) for more details.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like what I need.  However, something is weird.  I have a RelativeLayout with an android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar inside on the top.  It also uses android:fitsSystemWindows="true".  After adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to a RelativeLayout beneath it, the toolbar appears behind the status bar.  The toolbar looks perfect if android:fitsSystemWindows="true" is not used for the RelativeLayout beneath it.  Do you have any idea why so?

Comment: In [this article](https://medium.com/@azizbekian/windowinsets-24e241d4afb9): `Standard layouts like FrameLayout , LinearLayout or RelativeLayout will not pass window insets to their children, whereas “materialish” layouts will do`. Solution is provided there.