# What is the difference between LinearLayout and FitWindowsLinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

While creating a `Layout,` I cam across `FitWindowsLinearLayout` but can't seem to understand the difference between `LinearLayout` and `FitWindowsLinearLayout`.

So, when should we use `FitWindowsLinearLayout`?

[FitWindowsLinearLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1949ae9aeaadf52ad7bd7bb74ca5419c67ea7f65/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/FitWindowsLinearLayout.java)

Comment: you shouldnt use it - it is hidden (@hide annotation used)

Answer (score 3):

First, as you can see it is [annotated with `@hide`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/1949ae9aeaadf52ad7bd7bb74ca5419c67ea7f65/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/FitWindowsLinearLayout.java#25), which means, that it is not exposed to public API. That means that you should not use it.

Secondly, to answer your question: as you can see from the implementation, it has one public method, which sets a listener:

```
    public void setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(OnFitSystemWindowsListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

And this listener would be called when `fitSystemWindows(Rect)` is called:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFitSystemWindows(insets);
        }
        return super.fitSystemWindows(insets);
    }
```

This means, that you can retrieve `Rect insets` following way:

```
    FitWindowsLinearLayout layout = new FitWindowsLinearLayout(context);

    layout.setOnFitSystemWindowsListener(new OnFitSystemWindowsListener() {
        boolean onFitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
            // interact with `insets`
            return true;
        }
    })
```

To know what are insets see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585225/what-are-windowinsets/38929893#38929893) explanation.